# Indention and tabs in fundamental mode

Tags: indentation

*How can I control the indentation of a line in a plain text file?*

In `fundamental-mode`, when you begin to type a line (call it *Line A*) after a previous line by hitting <kbd>return</kbd>, the line will automatically inherit the indent of the previous line.

When I manually delete the automated indent, and want 3 tabs as indent instead by hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> three times, it seems that the second tab is converted to spaces, because I saw the cursor didn't jump by tab but by a character when I hit the second tab.

When I create another line (call it *Line B*) and remove any automated indent of it, if I hit just one <kbd>tab</kbd> key, it will jump to the same indent as that of *Line A*, and *Line A* has an indent more than just one tab.

Comment: Indentation in Emacs is meant to add as many space as needed to conform to the document requirements. It's the "requirement" of Fundamental mode that indent would be computed based on the current indent and the length of the word to the left on the line above it. It seems like what you wanted is simply to insert a TAB character, in which case you could type `C-q TAB`. I'm not sure if Emacs has a special mode for this kind of indenting, but there's a good chance it has, giving Google a spin might be worthwhile.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, are you really editing in `fundamental-mode`?  If you're talking about a plain text file, are you sure you're not in `text-mode`?  You can check with `M-: major-mode`.

In general, have a look at the [manual node on "Indentation"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation.html).

<kbd>tab</kbd> runs `indent-for-tab-command` in `fundamental-mode`.  The first part of its docstring reads:

> Indent the current line or region, or insert a tab, as appropriate.
>   This function either inserts a tab, or indents the current line,
>   or performs symbol completion, depending on `tab-always-indent`.

You can control the tab stops via `tab-stop-list`:

> List of tab stop positions used by `tab-to-tab-stop`.
>   This should be a list of integers, ordered from smallest to largest.

If you'd prefer all of your tabs to be converted to spaces, you can [turn off `indent-tabs-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NoTabs) with `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)`.

If you'd like to prevent <kbd>enter</kbd> from [auto-indenting](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoIndentation), have a look at the threads for [How to disable auto-indentation of new lines?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5939/how-to-disable-auto-indentation-of-new-lines) and [Emacs version 24.4: New obnoxious loss of indentation on hitting RETURN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718310/emacs-version-24-4-new-obnoxious-loss-of-indentation-on-hitting-return).  Short version: either turn off `electric-indent-mode` or bind <kbd>enter</kbd> to `newline` rather than `newline-and-indent`.