# How to disable auto indentation in asm-mode

Tags: indentation

When programming in extended assembler (using `asm-mode`), auto indentation insists on indenting compiler directives, such as `#define`, `#if` and `#endif`, how can I disable this?

[image: problem example]

Emacs version: `0.300.0@26.3 (spacemacs)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting `electric-indent-mode` to `nil` on `asm-mode-hook` resolved the issue.

Comment: src: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5939/how-to-disable-auto-indentation-of-new-lines?rq=1